# On x-axis I have start date , intermediate dates , end date . I want highcharts to automatically adjust the intermediate dates

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using HighCharts .

On the x-axis I am trying to plot dates . The dates are coming from api. The api is dynamic, I can have weekly, monthly, yearly data.

The data is huge.

What I need to do : On the x-axis I have to always show the start date (first element of array, the end date (last element of the array), the intermediate dates (elements between first element and last element).

I can't show all the intermediate dates because they will be huge. So I am looking for a solution that should have start date, some intermediate dates, end date.

The problem I am facing : When I show start date and end date, I want the library to automatically adjust the intermediate dates. This is not happening. It only shows start date and end date.

This question is specific to highcharts. I am using Javascript.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hi @CodeOfLife, `So I am looking for a solution that should have start date, some intermediate dates, end date.` - this is exactly how Highcharts arranges x-axis by default. Could you adapt this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/muvqk6ce/ to show the problem?

Comment: So here you have very less dates . can you please increase the input at least 10 times what you have , then check it would not have the start values and end values.

Comment: @ppotaczek check this https://jsfiddle.net/z12eya7b/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` properties:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kLuc7ntb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOnTick

Comment: can you please check this https://jsfiddle.net/5cb6dkyL/ I don't know how it is taking 30th dec even if i have not passed 30th dec

Comment: @CodeOfLife, That's because Highcharts is not able to calculate evenly spaced ticks. You can use `tickPositions` or `tickPositioner` option to define ticks on your own. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions